# How to return index and value of the specific element from array on callback using any JavaScript array function?

Tags: javascript

I tried with `filter()` function but I'm not sure about returning index and value using that. here's sample code that I tried.

```
var names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
const name = names.filter((name, index) => name === 'G' ? console.log(${index}: ${name}) : null)
```

here variable `name` is useless because on call back I'm returning nothing.
However, I can access `index` and `name` inside callback but not sure about returning both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findIndex` instead

```
var names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
var valToFind = "G";
const valIndex = names.findIndex( s => s === valToFind );
```

you already know that the value is `valToFind`, so no need to return it.

Or as @PaulPro pointed out, if the values are just strings, then simply use

```
const valIndex = names.indexOf( valToFind );
```

Or you can wrap it in an object

```
var output = { name : valToFind, index : names.indexOf( valToFind ) };
```

Comment: If all you're doing is an equality check in the findIndex test you can also just use indexOf: `names.indexOf( valToFind )`

Comment: @Paulpro yeah, this is much simpler if the values are going to be a primitive value. Thanks.

Comment: Yes we can, But somehow can I return both using callback?

Comment: @SanjayShr return to whom?

Comment: To the variable. I ended up using one more array like this.                                       ```var names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];

let res=[];

const name = names.filter((name, index) => name === 'C' ? res.push(index, value): null)```

Comment: Check the edits, see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that is possible and I agree.